# How to detect an invalid C escaped string using a regular expression?

Tags: python, c, regex, escaping

I would like to find a regular expression (regex) that does detect if you have some invalid escapes in a C double quoted escaped string (where you can find double quotes only escaped).

I consider valid `\\` `\n` `\r` `\"` (the test string is using ")

A partial solution to this is to use `(?<!\\)\\[^\"\\nr]` but this one fails to detect bad escapes like `\\\`.

Here is a test string that I use to test the matching:

`...\n...\\b...\"...\\\\...\\\E...\...\\\...\\\\\..."...\E...`

The expression should match the last 6 blocks as invalid, the first 4 are valid. The problem is that my current version does find only 2/5 errors.

Comment: \\\E is invalid—the first slash escapes the second, and the third is trying to escape the E…

Comment: So you want to test if a *double quoted string* contains an invalid escape sequence?

Comment: Don't forget that C compilers actually allow: `\t\b\v\f\a\?\'` for the simple characters; they also allow `\o\oo\ooo` for octal escapes, and `\xX\xXX` for hex (and nominally more than two hex digits, in fact).  And C99 allows `\uXXXX` and `\U00XXXXXX` for hex-encoded Unicode characters too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*((?:\"|\\(?:[^\"\\nr]|$)))
```

That's the start of a string, or something that's not a backslash. Then some (possibly zero) properly escaped backslashes, then either an unescaped `"` or another backslash; if it's another backslash, it must be followed by something that is neither `"`, `\`, `n`, nor `r`, or the end of the string.

The incorrect escape is captured for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, the Python string would be `r"(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*((?:\"|\\(?:[^\"\\nr]|$)))"` (one more \ before the first double quote)

Comment: My editor doesn't require me to escape double-quotes; obviously I missed that one when I was escaping them all. D'oh. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(?:[^\\]+|\\[\\rn"])*(\\(?:[^\\rn"]|$))
```

If you have a match, you have an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: This doesn't match `"`, which is one of the thinks Sorin stated is invalid.