# Escaping \ in regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I was parsing a file and some lines of the file ended with "\". I wanted to use gsub to find and replace it. I tried '\' and /\/ and neither one correctly matched "\".

I ended up getting around it by using a combination of chop and strip but it left me thinking how would I do this if I ever need to again?

Comment: You might also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873652/how-to-detect-an-invalid-c-escaped-string-using-a-regular-expression/1873721#1873721

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the escape sign as well. So this should work:

```
/\\/
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing a string to gsub that will then be compiled to a regex:

```
"abc\def".gsub("\\", "")
=> "abcdef"
```

Or just providing the regex directly:

```
"abc\def".gsub(/\\/, "")
=> "abcdef"
```